# Type checking with generic Suppliers and lambdas

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I have two generic methods, which are designed to force the caller to provide parameters that match type wise:

```
private <T> void compareValues(Supplier<T> supplier, T value) {
    System.out.println(supplier.get() == value);
}

private <T> void setValue(Consumer<T> consumer, T value) {
    consumer.accept(value);
}
```

However, when calling them, the compiler reasons differently on what is allowed to pass as parameters:

```
compareValues(this::getString, "Foo"); // Valid, as expected
compareValues(this::getInt, "Foo");    // Valid, but compiler should raise error
compareValues(this::getString, 1);     // Valid, but compiler should raise error

setValue(this::setString, "Foo");      // Valid, as expected
setValue(this::setInt, "Foo");         // Type mismatch, as expected
setValue(this::setString, 1);          // Type mismatch, as expected


private String getString() {
    return  "Foo";
}

private int getInt() {
    return 1;
}

private void setString(String string) {
}

private void setInt(int integer) {
}
```

---

How come? Is the compiler just too clumsy to properly reason about types here, or is this a feature of the type system? If so, what are the rules that lead to this behavior? Also, how would I create a "type safe" version of compareValues without adding artificial parameters, if at all possible?

Please note, that the provided methods merely contain a dummy implementation and do not reflect the code in my actual code base. The focus here are solely the method calls.

Comment: Compiler infers the most common type for `compareValues()` arguments, so it turns out to be `Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>` for 2nd and 3rd `compareValues()` calls.

Comment: Also, note that you should probably be using `equals`.

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev in which cases the compiler does it?

Comment: @xagaffar in every case, the compiler tries to find the most common type, if it finds nothing it just chooses `Object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have mentioned why this is happening, so here's a solution to get around the problem.

If you create a generic class, separating the passing of the supplier from the passing of the argument, you do not give the compiler the opportunity to choose an intersection type:

```
public class Comparer<T>
{
    private final Supplier<T> supplier;

    Comparer(final Supplier<T> supplier)
    {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    void compare(T value)
    {
        System.out.println(supplier.get() == value);
    }
}

new Comparer<>(this::getString).compare("Foo"); // Valid, as expected
new Comparer<>(this::getInt).compare("Foo"); // Invalid, compiler error
new Comparer<>(this::getString).compare(1);  // Invalid, compiler error
```

By separating out this behaviour, you also allow `Comparer` to do potentially useful things like caching the result of `Supplier.get()`.

Comment: Great idea! And it just so happens, that this approach fits my actual code quite well. Thanks!

Comment: I picked this answer, because it ultimately lead to better code in my project. Other answers deserve some praise as well, but I can accept only one, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell that the compiler choose an intersection type, by using

```
javac -XDverboseResolution=deferred-inference
```

output in one of the cases is:

```
 instantiated signature: (Supplier<INT#1>,INT#1)void
 target-type: <none>

 where T is a type-variable:
 T extends Object declared in method <T>compareValues(Supplier<T>,T)

 where INT#1,INT#2 are intersection types:
 INT#1 extends Object,Serializable,Comparable<? extends INT#2>
 INT#2 extends Object,Serializable,Comparable<?>
```

Comment: The plot thickens! I was not aware, that the Java type system is able to infer common/intersection types. Do you happen to have an idea how to force the compiler to be less smart and more strict?

Comment: @PatrickPeer you can add a witness `compareValues(Supplier<T> supplier, T value, Class<T> clazz)` that is really unused

Comment: @ Eugene I was aware of this approach, but for the API I try to create it is an artificial parameter, which makes using my code clunkier than it needs to be. Good idea though!

Answer (score 1):

Well here `T` can be anything. It is a synonym of a type but can be basically any type.

So when you have a  `compareValues(Supplier<T> supplier, T value)`  it means a supplier that can give me any type and value that can be of any type. So it doesn't give a compile error and it even works. In your method you can do:

```
private <T> void compareValues(Supplier<T> supplier, T value) {
    value=supplier.get();  //It is still valid even if you give different types
    System.out.println((supplier.get() == value) +" - "+ value);
}
```

As for the other method it is different because you say "Give me a consumer that accepts any type" but you give him a consumer that accepts just String.

So here

```
private void setString(String s) {

    }
```

won't work but

```
private <T> void setString(T s) {

}
```

will work just fine.

It's like if you have a variable of type Object you can assign String to it but not the other way around in a more bizarre situation. A String supplier is a `<T>` supplier but a String consumer is not a `<T>` consumer.

See these two methods:

```
    private <T> void setString(T a) {
        T var=a;
        T var2="Asdf"; //This doesn't compile! cannot convert String to T
    }

    private <String> void setString2(String a) {
        String var=a;
        String var2="asd";
    }
```

You want consumer of type T which the first method is. But instead you try to give a consumer of type String which cannot work because it consumes just Strings and you want a method that can consume everything

Comment: Unfortunately I still fail to see how T in compareValues can be of any type (I provide a specific Supplier in the call, after all). Also, even though I like your "human friendly" explanation, this time I am looking for a more in depth technical answer ;)

Comment: Well I thought that is technical enough. You can not narrow the expected type. When you expect a Consumer<T> (basically a consumer that consumers can consume any type <T>) if you supply a Consumer<String> you basically narrow the type and if in the method there is code using Consumer<T> it might not work with Consumer<String>